# ASSIMP Skinning seems to be somewhat inverted

Tags: opengl, skeletal-animation, glm, assimp, skinning

I'm currently implementing Skinning using Assimp as my asset importer. I've relied heavily on the following tutorial in order to skin meshes (http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) So some of you might be familiar with the code. I'm also using GLM as my math library.

In order to successfully cast Assimp matrices to GLM matrices (If I recall they are in a different order so have to be transposed), I have the following helper functions:

```
static inline glm::vec3 vec3_cast(const aiVector3D &v) { return glm::vec3(v.x, v.y, v.z); } 
static inline glm::vec2 vec2_cast(const aiVector3D &v) { return glm::vec2(v.x, v.y); } // it's aiVector3D because assimp's texture coordinates use that
static inline glm::quat quat_cast(const aiQuaternion &q) { return glm::quat(q.w, q.x, q.y, q.z); } 
static inline glm::mat4 mat4_cast(const aiMatrix4x4 &m) { return glm::transpose(glm::make_mat4(&m.a1)); }
static inline glm::mat4 mat4_cast(const aiMatrix3x3 &m) { return glm::transpose(glm::make_mat3(&m.a1)); }
```

Now, when calculating the transformation matrix of a bone, the following method is used:

```
void AnimatedMesh :: ReadNodeHeirarchy(float AnimationTime, const aiNode* pNode, const glm::mat4& ParentTransform)
{    
    string NodeName(pNode->mName.data);

    const aiAnimation* pAnimation = m_Animations[0];

    glm::mat4 NodeTransformation = mat4_cast(pNode->mTransformation);

    const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim = FindNodeAnim(pAnimation, NodeName);

    if (pNodeAnim) 
    {
        // Interpolate scaling and generate scaling transformation matrix
        aiVector3D Scaling;
        CalcInterpolatedScaling(Scaling, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(Scaling.x, Scaling.y, Scaling.z);
        glm::mat4 ScalingM = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), scale);

        // Interpolate rotation and generate rotation transformation matrix
        aiQuaternion RotationQ;
        CalcInterpolatedRotation(RotationQ, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
        glm::quat rotation = quat_cast(RotationQ);
        glm::mat4 RotationM = glm::toMat4(rotation);

        // Interpolate translation and generate translation transformation matrix
        aiVector3D Translation;
        CalcInterpolatedPosition(Translation, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
        glm::vec3 translation = glm::vec3(Translation.x, Translation.y, Translation.z);
        glm::mat4 TranslationM = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), translation);

        // Combine the above transformations
        NodeTransformation = TranslationM * RotationM * ScalingM;
    }

    glm::mat4 GlobalTransformation = ParentTransform * NodeTransformation;

    if (m_BoneMapping.find(NodeName) != m_BoneMapping.end()) 
    {
        unsigned int BoneIndex = m_BoneMapping[NodeName];
        m_BoneInfo[BoneIndex].FinalTransformation = m_GlobalInverseTransform * GlobalTransformation * m_BoneInfo[BoneIndex].BoneOffset;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pNode->mNumChildren; i++) 
    {
        ReadNodeHeirarchy(AnimationTime, pNode->mChildren[i], GlobalTransformation);
    }
}
```

We calculate the final position of the bone in the vertex shader like this:

```
#version 440 core

#define ANIMATED_MESH
#define MAX_BONES 100

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 aTangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 aBitangent;
#ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
layout (location = 5) in uvec4 BoneIDs;
layout (location = 6) in vec4 Weights;
#endif

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec3 Normal;
out mat3 TBN;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
#ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
uniform mat4 gBones[MAX_BONES];
#endif

void main()
{
    vec4 pos = vec4(aPos, 1.0f);

#ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
    mat4 BoneTransform = gBones[BoneIDs[0]] * Weights[0];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[1]] * Weights[1];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[2]] * Weights[2];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[3]] * Weights[3];
    pos               *= BoneTransform;
#endif

    FragPos = vec3(model * pos);
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;

#ifdef NORMAL_MAP
    vec3 T = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aTangent, 0.0)));
    vec3 N = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aNormal, 0.0)));
    T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);
    vec3 B = cross(N, T);
    TBN = mat3(T, B, N);
#else
    Normal = transpose(inverse(mat3(model))) * aNormal;
#endif

#ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
    Normal *= BoneTransform.xyz;
#endif

    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}
```

Apologies for all the pasted code. I'm almost certain that the bone information is being sent properly and received in the vertex shader so my last thought is that it must be with calculating the transformation. This is strange to me as my code is exactly implemented how successful implementations of the same code. If you see here is the expected result taken inside Unity3D:
[image]

and this is my actual result taken from within my engine:
[image]

There are a few telling things in the actual result. First, the head goes far too forward, this to me seems like the head movement has been inverted and the bait's going as much forwards as it should be going backward.

Another thing is the leg on the left of the screen, instead of bending backwards, it tries to bend forwards. Lastly, and most obviously, is the arms, they seem twisted in towards each other. It seems the right arm is where the left arm should be and vice-versa.

I wanted to know if anyone could see where this issue could arise? All matrices taken from Assimp are cast into glm matrices using the helped functions mentioned above so they should be in the right format. This includes the bone offset matrices. If you need to see any more sections of the code, feel free to ask. I only tried to limit that amount of code pasted to where I thought the issue was most likely to avoid pasting too much code.

Thank you.

Comment: Which direction do your coordinate axes point in your asset's authored coordinate system? Which direction do your coordinate axes point in your engine's world space? If these don't match, you might need to do a handedness conversion when converting your matrices and quaternions.

Comment: Since I'm using GLM, the handedness is right-handed and I believe Assimp imports everything right-handed as well by default (it should handle the conversions if I'm not mistaken). I'll double-check this information

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah, Assimp is right-handed and opengl in world space is right handed but I think you have something with the handedness. The strange thing is, someone else (http://www.xphere.me/2019/05/bones-animation-with-openglassimpglm/) used the same libraries as me and did the same tricks as me to get them to work together but it works for them and not me. Everything I import has the bones translate in such an odd way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was in the vertex shader. When calculating gl_Position, I was doing this

```
gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
```

Where FragPos was calculated as follows:
    vec4 pos = vec4(aPos, 1.0f);

```
mat4 BoneTransform = gBones[BoneIDs[0]] * Weights[0];
BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[1]] * Weights[1];
BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[2]] * Weights[2];
BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[3]] * Weights[3];
pos               *= BoneTransform;

FragPos = vec3(model * pos);
```

As you can see, this completely removes the w component of the vector and thus gave weird results. My updated shader is this:

```
#version 440 core

#define ANIMATED_MESH
#define NORMAL_MAP
#define MAX_BONES 100

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 aTangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 aBitangent;
#ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
layout (location = 5) in uvec4 BoneIDs;
layout (location = 6) in vec4 Weights;
#endif

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec2 TexCoords;
#ifdef NORMAL_MAP
out mat3 TBN;
#else
out vec3 Normal;
#endif

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
#ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
uniform mat4 gBones[MAX_BONES];
#endif

void main()
{
    vec4 PosL = vec4(aPos, 1.0f);

#ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
    mat4 BoneTransform = gBones[BoneIDs[0]] * Weights[0];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[1]] * Weights[1];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[2]] * Weights[2];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[3]] * Weights[3];
    PosL               = BoneTransform * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
#endif

    FragPos = vec3(model * PosL);
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;

#ifdef NORMAL_MAP
    #ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
        vec3 T = normalize(vec3(model * BoneTransform * vec4(aTangent, 0.0)));
        vec3 N = normalize(vec3(model * BoneTransform * vec4(aNormal, 0.0)));
    #else
        vec3 T = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aTangent, 0.0)));
        vec3 N = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(aNormal, 0.0)));
    #endif

    T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);
    vec3 B = cross(N, T);
    TBN = mat3(T, B, N);

#else
    #ifdef ANIMATED_MESH
        Normal = transpose(inverse(mat3(model))) * aNormal * BoneTransform.xyz;
    #else
        Normal = transpose(inverse(mat3(model))) * aNormal;
    #endif
#endif

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * PosL;
}
```

Where we multiple the final bone transform (PosL) as a complete 4 component vector